# How to Label and Caption a Tikzpicture inside a tabular environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, cross-referencing, captions

What is the correct way to label and captionize a tkizpicture inside a tabular environment? (Since figures are not allowed inside a tabular)

Excerpt from my .tex:

```
\begin{tabular}{l r}

&
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   ... % I want to label this tikzpicutre and give it a nice caption
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
```

Outside the tabular I would have done it like this:

```
   \begin{figure}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   ... 
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \label{fig:...}\caption{...}
   \end{figure}
```

Basically I want to create a page that looks like this:

```
----------------------------
|Text Text    TKIZ    TKIZ |
|TextText     TKIZ    TKIZ |
| Text Text   Figure X: ...|
|                          |
|This text is under the    |
|table and references above|
|TKIZ Figure with \ref{..} |
----------------------------
```

Comment: The "correct" way depends on a lot of factors, including what else is in the tabular (and perhaps why a tabular is needed in the first place).  Can you explain your exact problem a little more?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recommend to use the `\captionof` command of the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package (or load the tiny [`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) package instead). This command produces captions within other environments than figure or table and even lists them in the list of figures resp. tables.

Here's a complete example for demonstration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\bigskip
\section*{Test table}
\begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}}
Text text text &
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0,0) -> (4,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \captionof{figure}{Sample picture}
   \label{tikz}
\end{tabular}

See fig. \ref{tikz}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Btw. use `\label` *after* `\caption`, unlike in the example in your question.

Comment: Since v3.04, the KOMA-Script-classes also provide the `\captionof` command.

Comment: +1 for the tip "put \label after \caption", saved my day!

Comment: Super good answer, since it does not need `figure` to be used.

Comment: This is working great for me, with one exception. I was sometimes getting a page break inserted between the figure and the caption. I wrapped it in "`absolutelynopagebreak`" from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94702 .