# Include image in a table

Tags: tables, graphics, cross-referencing

> **Duplicate of:**
>   [How to Label and Caption a Tikzpicture inside a tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6438/how-to-label-and-caption-a-tikzpicture-inside-a-tabular-environment)

I am trying to include an image inside a table cell. But I am declaring the image using the `figure` environment, where I can include a label to reference to inside the document (that's why I did't use `\includegraphics`, because this hasn't got a label to use as reference)

As it appears to be, I can't put the `figure` environment inside a table, because they are incompatible. But this is the only way I know for later referencing inside the text.

Comment: Sorry, I think I entered the wrong number. I wanted to suggest http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float as a duplicate.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6438/how-to-label-and-caption-a-tikzpicture-inside-a-tabular-environment in also related.

Comment: @Caramdir: I removed the wrong duplicate as requested. Turns out it can be simply edited away. :-)