# Unbreakable section

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I would like to know if there is any global command that would prevent any page-breaks inside sections. All my sections are short enough. I read some solutions, such as [Absolutely, definitely, preventing page break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94699/absolutely-definitely-preventing-page-break), but I would like an automatic solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `\filbreak` before `\section`; you can automate it with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\section{\filbreak}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Two}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Three}
\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```