# Set a different page layout for a single page in Memoir

Tags: margins, memoir, layout

I've set a page layout for my entire document with a space for margin notes with the following `memoir` commands:

```
\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\settypeblocksize{7.5in}{4.3in}{*}
\setlrmargins{1.5cm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{20pt}{6.2cm}{0pt}

\checkandfixthelayout
```

The problem is that now I want some of the pages not to have the margin notes space, yet conserving the margins. That is, I want the blocksize to be extended on width, occupying the space of the margin notes. If it's possible, I'd like to have all the settings into an environment, such as the following:

```
\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
   % The settings that would make the layout go fullwidth
}{%
   % The settings that would make the layout return to its normal lengths
}
```

I've seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284486/set-a-different-layout-for-a-single-page-in-memoir) question as well, but for some reason it couldn't solve my case.

Comment: It should be noted that you cannot change the column width in the middle of a paragraph (even using flowfram).  What you **can** do is manually break the paragraph at the end of a page (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385284/connection-of-two-specific-paragraphs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workable? extension to my original partial answer. Check my redefinition of the `fullwidth` environment.

```
% mempageprob.tex  SE 643135

\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\settypeblocksize{7.5in}{4.3in}{*}
\setlrmargins{1.5cm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{20pt}{6.2cm}{0pt}

\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
  \clearpage
  \settypeblocksize{7.5in}{3.3in}{*}   %% this doesn't work (reduces the header but not the text)
  \checkandfixthelayout
}{%
  \clearpage
  \settypeblocksize{7.5in}{4.3in}{*} 
  \checkandfixthelayout
   }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{fullwidth}
  \lipsum[4-6]
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[7-9]

\newpage
\renewenvironment{fullwidth}{%
  \twocolumn
  \settypeblocksize{7.5in}{3.3in}{*}   
  \checkandfixthelayout
  \onecolumn}
{%
  \twocolumn
  \settypeblocksize{7.5in}{4.3in}{*} 
  \checkandfixthelayout
  \onecolumn}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{fullwidth}
  \lipsum[4-6]
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[7-9]

\end{document}
```

In (La)TeX  the whole page layout is reconfigured when going between `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn`. The revised version of `fullwidth` does the `\two/onecolumn` switching and gives, I believe, the desired result. Whenever LaTeX switches between `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` it starts a new page.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer.

```
% mempageprob.tex  SE 643135

\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\settypeblocksize{7.5in}{4.3in}{*}
\setlrmargins{1.5cm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{20pt}{6.2cm}{0pt}

\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
  \clearpage
  \settypeblocksize{7.5in}{3.3in}{*}   %% this doesn't work (reduces the header but not the text)
  \checkandfixthelayout
}{%
  \clearpage
  \settypeblocksize{7.5in}{4.3in}{*} 
  \checkandfixthelayout
   }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{fullwidth}
  \lipsum[4-6]
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[7-9]

\end{document}
```

My `fullwidth` environment changes the width of the header (the position of the page number) but does not change the textwidth. I don't know why: hopefully someone else will be able to provide a workable answer.

Comment: I've tried implementing this but i encounter the same issue as you. Maybe I'll have to post another question on why this does not change the textwidth.

Comment: @rodryx11 Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643343 which may be of some help. It locally changes the margins (and hence the `\textwidth`)