Changing margins mid-document with memoir
I'm writing a one-sided book-type document using memoir and would like to change the size of the side margins for a few pages midway through.
I have tried using the \setlrmarginsandblock command but it doesn't behave as I expect (and since I need to change the margins for more than one page, the minipage environment is not a suitable solution).
Here is a minimum working example with the resulting output below (compiled with LuaTeX as I'm using an external font for the real document):
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}

% set default margins
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}

% for dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\clearpage
% make margins larger for second page
\setlrmarginsandblock{4.5cm}{4.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout%
\lipsum[4-6]

\clearpage
% reset margins to default
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout%
\lipsum[7-9]

\end{document}


As you can see, while the left-hand side margin is increased in the second page, the right-hand side margin doesn't behave in the same way.
How can I increase both margins by the same amount?
I've looked at a few related questions on this site but wasn't able to find a solution.

Try the memoir environment adjustwidth

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}

    
% set default margins
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

% for dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \clearpage

    % increase both margins locally by 1cm <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643370/161015
    \begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}
        \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{adjustwidth}
    
    \clearpage
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
\end{document}

If you want the page numbers to be aligned with the left margin of the text, use this code:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{showframe} % only to show the margins <<<

% set default margins
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

% for dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \clearpage
    
    \setlrmarginsandblock{4.5cm}{4.5cm}{*}
    \checkandfixthelayout%

    % change both margins locally  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643370/161015
    \begin{adjustwidth}{0cm}{2cm}
        \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{adjustwidth}
    
    \clearpage      
    
    \setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
    \checkandfixthelayout%
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
\end{document}


