# Force paragraph to stay on same page where it began

Tags: page-breaking

I am organizing several abstracts for a conference booklet; some of them are too long, thus inducing a page break.

After finishing the booklet layout I am going to edit the abstracts to make them shorter and ensure that each occupies only one page, but for now I would like to *force* each abstract to stay inside its own page even if this means that the text will "bleed" below the current page.

Is this attainable in LaTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Probably you could use `minipages`.

Comment: Here are also two related questions: [Absolutely, definitely, preventing page break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94699/134144)  and [Unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4471/134144)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\filbreak` (The TeXbook, page 111).

> The most interesting macro that plain TeX provides for page make-up is called `\filbreak`. It means, roughly, “Break the page here and fill the bottom with blank space, unless there is room for more copy that is itself followed by `\filbreak`.” Thus if you put `\filbreak` at the end of every paragraph, and if your paragraphs aren’t too long, every page break will occur between paragraphs, and TeX will fit as many
>   paragraphs as possible on each page. The precise meaning of `\filbreak` is
>
> ```
> \vfil\penalty-200\vfilneg
> ```
>
> according to Appendix B; and this simple combination of TeX’s primitives produces the desired result: If a break is taken at the `\penalty-200`, the preceding `\vfil` will fill the bottom of the page with blank space, and the `\vfilneg` will be discarded after the break; but if no break is taken at the penalty, the `\vfil` and `\vfilneg` will cancel each other and have no effect.

Here's an implementation.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newenvironment{abs}[2]
 {% #1 = title, #2 = author
  \par\vspace{\bigskipamount}\filbreak
  {\centering\textbf{#1}\par\vspace{1ex}\textit{#2}\par\vspace{1ex}}%
 }
 {\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{abs}{A title}{John Doe}
\lipsum*[1][1-3]
\end{abs}

\begin{abs}{A title}{John Doe}
\lipsum*[2][1-3]
\end{abs}

\begin{abs}{A title}{John Doe}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{abs}

\begin{abs}{A title}{John Doe}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{abs}

\begin{abs}{A title}{John Doe}
\lipsum*[1][1-3]
\end{abs}

\begin{abs}{A title}{John Doe}
\lipsum*[2][1-3]
\end{abs}

\begin{abs}{A title}{John Doe}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{abs}

\begin{abs}{A title}{John Doe}
\lipsum*[3-5]
\end{abs}

\end{document}
```

[image]