# Avoid vertical space in absolutelynopagebreak environment

Tags: environments, vertical-spacing

I like the idea of [absolutelynopagebreak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94702/292801) environment and I'd like to use it for wrapping theorem-like environments when needed (without modifying those environments).
It does work, but the problem is that it creates additional vertical space (before and after).

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{absolutelynopagebreak}
  {\par\nobreak\vfil\penalty0\vfilneg
   \vtop\bgroup}
  {\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
   \prevdepth=\tpd}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Statement 001.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Statement 002.
\end{theorem}

\begin{absolutelynopagebreak}
\begin{theorem}
Statement 003.
\end{theorem}
\end{absolutelynopagebreak}

\begin{theorem}
Statement 004.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Statement 005.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I was able to remove vertical space using `vspace` (approximately), but it's not reliable since it changes when text size changes.

```
\begin{absolutelynopagebreak}
\vspace{-1.3\baselineskip}
\begin{theorem}
Statement 006.
\end{theorem}
\vspace{-0.65\baselineskip}
\end{absolutelynopagebreak}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % For theorem environments

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{absolutelynopagebreak}
  {\par\@nobreaktrue\nobreak\penalty0}
  {\par\@nobreakfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Statement 001.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Statement 002.
\end{theorem}

\begin{absolutelynopagebreak}
\begin{theorem}
Statement 003.
\end{theorem}
\end{absolutelynopagebreak}

\begin{theorem}
Statement 004.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Statement 005.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The environment uses `\@nobreaktrue` and `\@nobreakfalse` to manage the page breaking behavior. This is a more direct approach and should interfere less with the natural spacing.
The `\penalty0` command is used to discourage page breaks without inserting additional space.

Comment: this doesn't prevent a pagebreak inside the theorem, add more lines (e.g. with \lipsum) to test that.