# How to Label and Caption TikzpictureS inside a tabular environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, captions

I want to use the nice answer to the similar question [How to Label and Caption a Tikzpicture inside a tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6438/how-to-label-and-caption-a-tikzpicture-inside-a-tabular-environment). The problem is I want two pictures side by side, with a caption for each. I duplicate the MWE to get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\bigskip
\section*{Test table}
\begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw [red](0,0) -> (4,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \captionof{figure}{Picture 1}
   \label{tikz1}
&
   \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw (0,0) -> (4,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \captionof{figure}{Picture 2}
   \label{tikz2}
\end{tabular}

\

See fig. \ref{tikz1} and  \ref{tikz2}.
\end{document}
```

but this does not compile, the error is

> (./captnof.lof) ! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
>   \caption@hrule ->\hrule 
>                           @height \z@
>   l.12    \captionof{figure}{Picture 1}

Once the line

```
\captionof{figure}{Picture 1}
```

is commented out, it does. So the

> \captionof

works for the right picture but not for the left one! Is there a way around?

Comment: The left column has no fixed width, if you use also a p column type for the left one, it should work.

Comment: Yes it does, make it an answer so that I can tag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\captionof` command requires one to specify the text width. So an ad hoc solution is to set the column type of the left column also to `p`. However, this requires us to know how the column will be. Since you are using `tikz`, there is an arguably better solution: let `tikz` measure the picture and adjust the text width accordingly. Both solutions are contained in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{caption/.style={insert path={
let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$) in
(current bounding box.south) node[below,text width=\x1-4pt,align=center] 
{\captionof{figure}{#1}}}}}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\bigskip
\section*{Test table}
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw [red](0,0) -> (4,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \captionof{figure}{Picture 1}
   \label{tikz1}
&
   \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw (0,0) -> (4,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \captionof{figure}{Picture 2}
   \label{tikz2}
\end{tabular}

See figs.~\ref{tikz1} and  \ref{tikz2}.

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw [red](0,0) -> (4,0);
         \path[caption={Picture 3.\label{tikz3}}];
   \end{tikzpicture}  
&
   \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw (0,0) -> (4,0);
         \path[caption={Picture 4.\label{tikz4}}];
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

See figs.~\ref{tikz3} and  \ref{tikz4}.
\end{document}
```

[image]